# How to make JEDI recognize a Python C extension

Tags: python, c, vim-plugin, jedi, jedi-vim

I am currently developing a Python module in C, and I cannot figure out how to make JEDI "see" my module.

I have set all docstrings in the C code and set every field in my `setup.py`, but when I edit the `example.py` file I use for testing and try to display documentation in vim using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, I get an error saying:

> Exception, this shouldn't happen.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/beben/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/jedi_vim.py", line 268, in show_documentation
>
> definitions = script.goto_definitions()
>
> File "/home/beben/.vim/bundle/jedi-vim/jedi/jedi/api/**init**.py", line 365, in goto_definitions
>
> names = [s.name for s in definitions]
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
>
> No documentation found for that.

After reading `jedi`'s documentation, I understand that it uses `Pydoc` to gather information on the module.
When I run `Pydoc mymodule`, the documentation is correctly displayed.

Is there something more that I need to add to my code to be recognized by JEDI?

Comment: Sounds like a Jedi issue. It's probably not hard to fix, but Jedi should definitely not raise an AttributeError there. Add it to the issue tracker! :)

Comment: Oh OK! I figured it could also be a bug on your side, but I did not want to bother you directly on the issue tracker, and the homepage said to post here for any questions, so I did!
Anyway, thank you for your quick reply, I'll post an issue!

Comment: Great, just add a reference to this post here.